# How to get precision with a small gear?

Tags: design, gears

I want to be able to precisely rotate a item. For this I have positioned the item on top of a very large gear. It is driven by a smaller gear. When the item is in the correct position, I will lock the smaller gear and the item is fixed in the correct position.

How can I achieve a more precise system without making the large gear larger and the small one smaller(without using motors)?

[image: Large gear has item on top of it and is driven by small gear]

Answer (score 1):

add intermediate gears, or consider an epicyclic reduction...

Or use a worm and gear, these can do higher ratios compared to gears in a similar volume... see https://www.motioncontroltips.com/worm-gears-what-are-they-and-where-are-they-used/